# Taxonomy of regression methods

Tags: regression

I am trying to organize regression methods so I know better in which branches to specialize. This is what I have so far and I need your help. First I divide based on the number of input and output variables, and then I divide in linear and non-linear.

[image: taxonomy]

Then for each of these four branches, I divide in two branches, linear or non-linear, making 8 total branches so far.

I am having problems naming the case of: 1 input variable, more than one output variables. Because it has more output variables, I can call it multivariate, but what do I call it for having one input variable? I can't call it simple, because simple means: 1 input variable 1 output variable.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps call it *simple-multivariate* regression but I doubt that the distinction from multiple multivariate is actually necessary.

You could simply subsume both under "multivariate regression", since there's no need to make a mathematical distinction between the two cases. (It may make your table slightly more awkward to construct but I think it's conceptually better because it avoids an unnecessary distinction.)